# GMT+2, TimeZone getOffset return 0

Tags: android

On Android (4.3) device, I set locate on TimeZone **GMT+2**

So my local time is **15.11.2017 15:12**

So as result the UTC is **15.11.2017 13:12**

minus (**2 hours**). OK.

I want to get timezone offset.

Here code:

```
private static TimeZone timeZoneUTC = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
private static Calendar calUTC = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); 

    public static int getTimeZoneRawOffset() {
        int offsetFromUtcMills = timeZoneUTC.getOffset(new Date().getTime());
        return offsetFromUtcMills;
    }

    public static int getTimeZoneOffset() {
        return calUTC.getTimeZone().getOffset(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
```

But both methods always return **0**.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm personally using

```
TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset();
```

To get the the offset for my default timezone.

Example:

```
ticket.getPurchaseDate().setTime(ticket.getPurchaseDate().getTime() + TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset());
```